# Рандомный спавн приложения winforms c#

Tags: c#, winforms

Как сделать так , что бы приложение рандомно выбирала в какую часть экрана спавниться через код c#-па?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Примерно так (писал в окне ответа, мог что-то напутать):

```
var rand = new Random();
var area = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea;

this.Left = rand.Next(area.Left, area.Right - this.Width);
this.Top = rand.Next(area.Top, area.Bottom - this.Height);
```